# Alterando um tipo de dado em todo o schema no oracle

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Boa tarde !
Preciso alterar um tipo de dados de todo o meu schema, tenho o `varchar2` tamanho 80, e gostaria de altera-lo para 100, mas isso tudo de uma vez... é possível ?

Comment: Toda coluna de se bd que for varchar2(80) vira (100) !?

Comment: isso, tem como ?

Comment: eu vi que tem como usar o alter type, mas não estou achando a sintaxe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

--

### --LOCALIZAR TODAS AS COLUNAS DE TIPO VARCHAR2 E TAMANHO 80 E ALTERAR PARA 100

--LISTAR ESTAS COLUNAS

```
SELECT *
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'VARCHAR2'
AND   DATA_LENGTH = 80
```

--MONTANDO UM SCRIPT

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' || TABLE_NAME || ' MODIFY ' || COLUMN_NAME || ' ' || DATA_TYPE || '(100)'
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'VARCHAR2'
AND   DATA_LENGTH = 80
```

--EXECUTANDO

```
BEGIN
  FOR R IN (SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' || TABLE_NAME || ' MODIFY ' || COLUMN_NAME || ' ' || DATA_TYPE || '(100)'
            FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
            WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'VARCHAR2'
            AND   DATA_LENGTH = 80) LINHA
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (R.LINHA);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

--generalizando

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ALTERA_TAMANHO(POWNER IN CHAR,
                                           PTAMDE NUMBER,
                                           PTAMPARA NUMVER) IS
BEGIN
  FOR R IN (SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' OWNER || '.' || TABLE_NAME || ' MODIFY ' || COLUMN_NAME || ' ' || DATA_TYPE || '(' || PTAMPARA || ')'
                FROM DBA_TAB_COLUMNS
                WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'VARCHAR2'
                AND   DATA_LENGTH = PTAMDE) LINHA
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (R.LINHA);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

--TIPO DA OPERAÇÃO QUE RECOMENDA UMA SALVA ANTES E SE POSSÍVEL EXECUÇÃO ANTES --EM AMBIENTE DE  TESTES

Comment: Primeiramente muito obrigado Motta, mas é de todo o meu schema, eu entendo muito bem de sql server, mas no oracle estou derrapando...

Comment: eu estou tentando uma solução que é um seguinte...fazer uma procedure recebendo o owner, tamnhoAtual, tamanhoAlterar, e criaria um cursor, recebendo esses parametros no select do cursor, passaria o owner e o varchar, e a cada linha do cursor, jogaria um alter table, modificando a coluna

Comment: A solução postada se aplica a Oracle apenas ! Esta sua alteração teria um volume tão grande que justificasse generalizar para uma Procedure , vou generalizar a solução

Comment: estou estudando o oracle, e estou criando a proc e ao execut-la, está me dando um erro, ORA- 00900: invalid SQL statement
fiz dessa forma:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "PROC_TESTE_SELECT"
IS
BEGIN
 SELECT * FROM DBA_TAB_COLUMNS 
 WHERE OWNER ='TESTE'
END PROC_TESTE_SELECT
**********************************************
EXEC PROC_TESTE_SELECT
PROC_TESTE_SELECT

ATÉ CRIA A PROC, MAS NÃO EXECUTA... FICA DANDO ERRO :(

Comment: Select "soltos" em plsql devem retornar uma e apenas uma linha e precisam retornar para uma variável.

Comment: PENSEI EM ALGO ASSSIM:

Comment: DECLARE CURSOR cur_alterar_varchar2_para_80 
      SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
      WHERE DATA_TYPE= ‘VARCHAR2’ AND DATA_LENGTH = 80

       V_NM_TABELA USER_TAB_COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME%TYPE
       V_NM_TABELA USER_TAB_COLUMNS. COLUMN_NAME %TYPE
BEGIN
       OPEN cur_alterar_varchar2_para_80
 FETCH cur_alterar_varchar2_para_80 INTO V_NM_TABELA, V_NM_TABELA
 ALTER TABLE V_NM_TABELA (V_NM_TABELA VARCHAR2(100))
       CLOSE cur_alterar_varchar2_para_80 
END

Comment: minha procedure não atendeu ?